# (R) Can anyone suggest me an algorithm for highest density interval?

Tags: r, bayesian

While studying bayesian statistics, an interval estimation called HPD interval comes in, and I am trying to find HPD interval of 95% of beta distribution.

I've tried several ways, but finding an algorithm that finds HPD interval was difficult.

I want to use:

```
p <- seq(0, 1, length = 100)
density <- dbeta(p, 7, 25)
```

to find HPD interval.

Another question would be I know that we get density value from computing `dbeta(p, 7, 25)`, but is there an inverse function of dbeta? I was trying to get the p with corresponding density value.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: inverses of density functions are not used very much because most density functions aren't one-to-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the code of `TeachingDemos::hpd`. You need the inverse cdf (`icdf`).

```
function(posterior.icdf, conf=0.95, tol=0.00000001,...){
    conf <- min( conf, 1-conf )
    f <- function(x,posterior.icdf,conf,...){
        posterior.icdf(1-conf+x,...) - posterior.icdf(x,...)
    }
    out <- optimize(f, c(0,conf), posterior.icdf = posterior.icdf,
                        conf=conf, tol=tol, ...)
    return( c( posterior.icdf(out$minimum,...), 
               posterior.icdf(1-conf+out$minimum,...) ) )
}
```

Make a picture, you will see it's easy.

Comment: In particular, you'll want something like `hpd(function(x) qbeta(x, 7, 25))` ...